# Job Title for This Skill Set?

Tags: title

This might be an odd question and perhaps this is not the correct forum so please advise if I am in the wrong location.

A few years ago I read a book which mentions that individuals who can absorb a new topic very quickly and can become an expert at it are called "Universals" (that is if my memory serves me right).

Is this the correct term? Is there another term for these creatures with sponge-like brains?

Thanks for the assist!

Comment: Field agent? You seem to be describing MacGuyver and that's his job title.

Answer (score 2):

It's not recognised as a skill set. It's a talent called 'Quick Learner'. Which almost everyone reckons they have. I have seen it listed in many CV's. It's not really boasting, it just means that you have the ability to learn quickly.

In reality it's just experience and learning strategies, both in how to absorb knowledge and how to put it together usefully. It's a huge part of what is learnt in school and home. The key is in understanding what you're absorbing and applying it. Some people are better at it than others, just like everything else in life.

Answer (score 1):

### Don't title yourself this, regardless of what you call it

This would be along the same lines as calling oneself a very stable genius and would just set one up for ridicule.  If someone were truly an expert in everything they'd have no need of a job, they'd already be running the world.

Instead, resume writers should give examples of when they learned things quickly to get results.  If they're a smart as this, people will figure it out quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Save this for the interview, and stick to straightforward facts in your CV. Otherwise, if you must, then either: write about it where you elaborate on your job tasks, or write "jack of all trades" as a skill.